# Números reales en c#

Tags: c#, float

¿Cómo imprimir el valor completo de un número real en c#?

La divisón de `21/60 = 0.35`

En mi código de C# tengo

```
int n1 = 21;
int n2 = 60;

double n3 = n1/n2;

Console.WriteLine("{0:00.0}", n3);
```

También  lo hice de esta manera

```
Console.Write(String.Format("{0:#.0}", n3));
```

En consola sólo imprime `0.0` o `.0` y necesito el valor completo de números decimales, flotantes etc. como `0.35` o `o.75262`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que tenes que hacer es declarar n1 y n2 como double también

De la siguiente manera te va a mostrar 0.35

```
 double n1 = 21;
 double n2 = 60;

 double n3 = n1 / n2;

 Console.WriteLine(n3);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: No es necesario declarar `n1` o `n2` como `double` (salvo que sean valores decimales). Basta con castear la division, ej: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2NMcQi

Answer (score 2):

En el supuesto que no puedas cambiar la declaración de n1 y n2, que estos sean casteados como doubles por ejemplo:

```
int n1= 21;
int n2=17;

double n3 = (double)n1/n2;

Console.WriteLine( n3);
```

esto genera como output:  1,23529411764706

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2NMcQi

Comment: @EmanuelVe Corregido, añadido que es un casting no una declaración, y especificado que es una solución cuando n1 y n2 son ints y no puedes cambiarlo.